# Anaconda-Navigator.app missing after installation on M1 macOS Monterey

Tags: python, anaconda3

I installed Anaconda, but it did not include the GUI app, Anaconda-Navigator app in the Applications folder. What do I need to do to get the GUI app?

Details:
Computer: 2021 14-inch MacBook Pro, M1 Max
OS: macOS Monterey 12.5

A month ago, I had the full Intel version of Anaconda, including Anaconda-Navigator, running fine.

I decided I wanted the M1 version, so I uninstalled it using the method detailed on the Anaconda website (anaconda-clean), rm -rf ~/opt/anaconda3, and remove conda section of .zshrc. I also deleted Anaconda-Navigator from the Applications folder and removed all ~/Library/Receipts, and restarted the laptop.

I the used the GUI installer for the M1 version, which set up conda and seemingly the complete ~/anaconda3 folder, but it didn't install the Anaconda-Navigator app.

I repeated the full uninstall and used the shell installer, getting the same result - no Anaconda-Navigator.

Any suggestions on how I can get Anaconda-Navigator GUI?

Thanks!!
Mike

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on my own. Anaconda Navigator is *not included* with the M1 version. I read the *complete* Anaconda press release [1](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/new-release-anaconda-distribution-now-supporting-m1), as I should have done before I posted my question. A flag for me was that the file size of the installation package for the M1 was quite a bit smaller than for Intel.

Comment: I had the same problem. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 7):

run -> conda install anaconda-navigator

Worked for my on my Mac mini M1. Was looking for ages to find this. Hope this helps someone looking for it as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm struggling with these issues now.  Still doesn't seem to be documented and Anaconda.com's list of included packages for the ARM installer threw me off by listing "anaconda-navigator" as included "In Installer".. https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.9_osx-arm64/

What you need to do is, after running the ARM64 installer..  run -> conda install anaconda-navigator

Still trying to figure out why Anaconda Navigator.app runs fine on an M1 Air and M1 Mini.. but won't launch on a M1 Max MBP.   I have a feeling it's because she used Migration Assistant to migrate her user account.. and there's crud in her old config files that are breaking things (without logging why).  :-/

Comment: I agree that it is odd that it won't run on one of three M1s you have.  

Thank you for sharing the link to the packages info. It's interesting that for ARM64 the version of anaconda-navigator is 2.2.0, but it's 2.1.4 for Intel x86. Also the most recent release notes only mention 2.1.4.

Things are fast enough for me with the x86 version, and I am using Qt, so I'm not willing to install it on my system at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. After installing with `conda install anaconda-navigator` run it from terminal with `anaconda-navigator` and lock it to the  Dock (right click -> options -> keep in dock)

Comment: Pinning it to the dock is a great idea! Since my post, I have uninstalled Navigator, instead using pyenv to install Python versions and venv for virtual environments. I've installed the packages I need (e.g., Jupyter Notebook, pandas, matplotlib) via pip. I'm pleased with the flexibility it allows me.